# How display some cell without button and some with a button in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewbuttoncolumn

I have a DataGridView and I want in my grid a column having some cells that display a button and some cells that do not contain the button.
In order to solve this problem I've added a DataGridViewButtonColumn and I've written this method that I call to add the rows to my column:

```
 private void AttachNewRow(bool validRow)
 {
     DataGridViewRow newRow = GetNewRow();
     if (validRow)
     {
         newRow.Cells["Info"].Value = "Click me";
     }
     else
     {
         // Here I would like to hide the button in the cell
         newRow.Cells["Info"].Value = null;
     }
 }
```

The problem is that when I set the cell value to null I receive an exception.
How can I display some of these cells without the button inside?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `GetNewRow()` returns the `Row` you are talking about already inserted in the `DGV`.

If that function has the knowledge if the 'Info' `Column` shall contain a `Button`, it can pass it, maybe in the `Tag`:

```
if (somecondiiotn) newRow.Columns["Info"].Tag = "Button";
```

Then you can write:

```
private void AttachNewRow()
{
    DataGridViewRow newRow = GetNewRow();
    if ( newRow.Cells["Info"].Tag == null || 
         newRow.Cells["Info"].Tag != "Button") return;
    //..
```

If otoh the code that calls `AttachNewRow()` has the required knowledge, it could instead pass it on in a parameter:

```
private void AttachNewRow(bool infoButton)
```

If the knowlegde is available only later you can still change individual cells.

Update:

since you are now passing the condition into the method you can act accordingly.

I don't know why you get an exception in your code - I don't. But to really hide the `Button` you should change the cell to be a 'normal' `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`:

```
else
{
   DataGridViewCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
   newRow.Cells["Info"] = cell;
```

Comment: Hi TaW, I've tried to rewrite the question because of your reply I realized it was not clear. It's clear now what I mean?Thank you very much

Comment: See the updated answer. How come you crash? On which line? Have you changed the code, so that the info column is a button column to start with? I have assumed you do that now and simply change the invalid rows back. You can switch them back to Button in the same way if and when they get valid..

Comment: The exception was on the line newRow.Cells["Info"].Value = null; your answer solved my problem, thank you very much

Comment: Strange, I could do that.. But if it works as you need it, all is well. btw: danish got a good point inserting `ReadOnly = true;`

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this in RowAdded event handler. Here it is assumed that third column is button column:

```
if (condition)
        {

            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2]  = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].ReadOnly = true;
        }
```